# Database schema for users, games, historical relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to determine the best organization of my database.  I have a users table that has a column for each individual's `current_game`.  (Each user can only belong to one game at any given time.)  There is a games table where each particular game has a unique id.

I can perform all of my queries/operations just fine this way.  However, I want to maintain a record of each users prior games, so that they can access their historical data and statistics.

Since games only last for so long--weeks, say--and since not all users will always be actively engaged in a game, this is the schema I was considering:

`users`, `users_inactive`, `games`, `games_old`, `game_events`, `game_events_old`

My concerns are 2: First, is two users tables going to be problematic for logins and registrations?  Second, do I have to maintain a two column `membership` table with a row for every user-game relationship (so 8 users each having been in 5 past games means 40 rows in the `membership` table), or is there a simpler, more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be introduce a boolean column to indicate whether the entity is active or not.

For example,  instead of "games" and "games_old" tables, I would use game_active (boolean column) in "games" table and eliminate the "games_old" table.  In the business logic, you will have to mark the new games as active and old games as inactive.

The same logic applies to other tables as well.

The constraints will  look like,

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `game_id`),
INDEX `idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
INDEX `idx_game_id` (`game_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_users_user_game` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_games_user_game` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`game_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: What about the `membership` issue?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part.  According to me, YES you have to have a two column table for user-game relationship as this is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: And create a composite primary key with "user_id" and "game_id".

Comment: Do Foreign Keys have a place here, or is that a moot issue?

Comment: Foreign Keys have definite place here.  `user_id` and `game_id` should have foreign key constraints with `users` and `games` tables.

Comment: Thanks for that.  This is an appropriate query then?:  `CREATE TABLE UserMatches (
  uid int(11) NOT NULL,
  mid int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('uid', 'mid'),
  INDEX 'idx_uid' ('uid'),
  INDEX 'idx_mid' ('mid'),
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_users_user_game' FOREIGN KEY ('uid') REFERENCES 'users' ('uid') ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_matches_user_game' FOREIGN KEY ('gid') REFERENCES 'matches' ('mid') ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: Yes it is.  But if you want to store the timestamps for each record, you can add columns respectively.

Comment: I am assuming `missions` table is `matches` table.  You are trying to insert wrong data into the table.  Please read about foreign key constraint exceptions and then check the data you are trying to insert.  I am basically a Java developer and I have no knowledge on php.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `current_game` column from the `users` table and add a new table that connects users with games together with a start and end timestamp. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE user_games (
    user_id INT,
    game_id INT,
    start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    end TIMESTAMP
);
```

For the current game, you would set `end` to NULL. When a user switches to a different game, update `end` and add a new row for the new game.

In order to query for the current game, just join the table on the condition that `end` is NULL. To query for historic games, just make sure the timestamp is between `start` and `end`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a `GameHistory` table

```
UserId | GameId 

1      | 563
```

I imagine the start and end date would be stored in the Games table. You could still store the current games id in the user table or create a bit field in the GameHistory table which would be called current game.

Comment: What about the membership issue?